# How to set default encoding and line delimiter in eclipse down to the workspace catalogues tree to UTF-8 and Unix automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, unix, encoding, utf-8

Whenewer i create a subtree of catalogues in my eclipse JAVA workspace,
the default Text file encoding for that subtree is always set to Cp1250
and new text file line delimiter to Windows.
I.e C:\Workspace\Java\Books as a root (where encoding is set to UTF-8 and line delimiter to UNIX)
and C:\Workspace\Java\Books\Author\book_name which I want to inherit encoding and line delimiter settings from 1st path

I always have to enter new branch of workspace and manually set those options
for each catalogue to UTF-8 and Unix.

I guess there is a way to set those options once for root catalogue, and apply them to sons automatically, but how to do that ?

I'm using Eclipse Neon.1 EE edition , and working in cloud workspaces only if that matters.

EDIT : I switched my workspace from cloud to desktop and nothing changed to me.

Answer (score 0):

In common Eclipse distributions, you can do the following: In your Eclipse, go to `Window > Preferences`. In the popup, navigate to `General > Workspace`. In the lower section on the right side, you should see two settings for `Text file encoding` and `New text file line delimiter`.

In the same window, you may also go to the upper left input field, type `encoding` and then go over every hit (in my case CSS, HTML, JSP and XML Files) and configure which encoding should be applied when creating new files.

Comment: Yeah, i know that. But that doesn't solve my problem, I mean if I apply that settings for specified catalogue, that changes that catalogue encoding and delimiter only, and doesn't force future sons to have same encoding as father.

Comment: Updated my post above for setting the default encoding for file creation.

Comment: I made every hit to UTF-8 (including >General > Content Types > Text to UTF-8 ) and new son catalogue doesn't inherited that encoding .. In >General > Workspace of son encoding it is still Cp1250 , not even mentioning the delimiter. And new Java Project made in this catalogue, same issue.

Comment: Maybe it's a cloud workspace setting. But I've got no experiences with those so far. Can you see / change those cloud properties?

Comment: Is that solution working for Your non-cloud workspace? Anyway thank You for Your time, regards :)

Comment: Yes it does. By default I create UTF-8/Unix files. For XML files I set UTF16. Then I added a custom file a.xml and a XML file b.xml. Be aware that when creating custom files with XML extension by hand it gets the workspace default UTF-8 whereas ```create new file ->XML -> XML file``` creates the expected UTF-16 encoded file. So maybe your settings will apply if you create the files via the correct wizard?

Comment: There's nothing weird: on my Windows machine I'm using a workspace with UTF-8/Unix and each folder and Java class files inherit the UTF-8/Unix settings from the workspace. Is it possible that these workspace settings are read-only/cannot be changed?